# Box api implemented in javascript - delete item

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to delete an item with box API, but unsuccessfully...
How can I do it using javascript?

I try to do it like a download request: (not working)
iframe.Src = https://www.box.net/api/1.0/delete/ACCESS TOKEN/ + FILE_ID;

and i try to it like an upload but its not working too:
add html form: form  id='fileipload1' action='https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/delete/o1f1hzcshcwqmbwzchycmqvtqj5hjxmi/0' method='post' target='iframe1' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
input type='submit' value='Submit'
input type='file' id='userImage21' name='pp'

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using the v1 of our API, which will be deprecated in a little over a month. You should probably developer against v2 instead. The delete method is documented here: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-delete-a-file